# In which form the data of facebook graph api me/home should be stored?

Tags: android, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I'm getting some user data with API `/me/home`. I want to ask that in which form shall I store the result- in `JSONArray` or `JSONObject`?

Please tell me the method to store data. I am using following procedure to get user data i am storing it in string now.

```
if (fb.isSessionValid()) {
   button.setImageResource(R.drawable.logout_button);
   pic.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
   JSONObject obj=null;
   JSONArray feed = null;
   URL img_url = null;
   try {
      String JSONUser = fb.request("me");
      obj = Util.parseJson(JSONUser);
      String id = obj.optString("id");
      String name = obj.optString("name");
      String newsfeed=fb.request("me/home");
```

Please help me.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Your question was poorly formatted and described. See here: [How to write a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of `/me/home` will be of form-

```
{
    "data":
       [
          .. .. ..
       ]
}
```

So, take the result in a JSONObject, then for the key `data` save the result to a JSONArray and then use the data.

You can always check the results of the Graph API in [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%2Fhome).